# How to scroll Horizontal UIScrollView without animation image gif Objectif-C

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

for more information:

I would like to display a gif image in a horizontal `UIScrollView` image = 1 pages.

I'd like to see this gif image at 4 pages for example.

I can add single image without `UIImageView` animation, but I can not button to add image with animated or even web container

Code with `UIScrollView`

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
// Création du ScrollView //
    //Put the names of our image files in our array.
    imageArray = [[NSArrayalloc] initWithObjects:@"page1.jpg",@"page2.jpg",@"page3.jpg",@"page4.jpg",@"page5.png",@"page6.png",@"page7.png",@"page8.jpg",@"page9.jpg",@"page10.jpg",@"page11.jpg",@"page12.jpg",@"page13.png",@"page14.jpg",@"page15.jpg",@"page16.jpg",@"page17.jpg",@"page18.png",@"page19.jpg",@"page20.jpg",@"page21.jpg",@"page22.png",@"page23.png",@"page24.png",@"page25.jpg",@"page26.jpg",@"page27.jpg",@"page28.jpg", nil];
    
    imageArray2 = [[NSArrayalloc]
                   initWithObjects:@"cercle1.tiff", @"cercle2.tiff", @"cercle3.tiff", nil];

    //Set the content size of our scrollview according to the total width of our imageView objects.
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [imageArraycount], scrollView.frame.size.height);

    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {
        //We'll create an imageView object in every 'page' of our scrollView.
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        
        imageView = [[UIImageViewalloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImageimageNamed:[imageArrayobjectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.scrollViewaddSubview:imageView];
        
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray2 count]; i++) {
        //We'll create an imageView object in every 'page' of our scrollView.
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        imageView = [[UIImageViewalloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImageimageNamed:[imageArray2objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.scrollViewaddSubview:imageView];
        
    }

#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    
    
    if (previousPage != page)
    {
        previousPage = page;
        
        if(page == 0)
        {

        }
        if(page == 1) // ETC...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling without animation can be done with `setContentOffset:animated:`, passing NO for the `animated` property.  Be aware that setting the contentOffset will cause `scrollViewDidScroll:` to be called, which could cause a loop if you're calling it within `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

**Edit**

I originally missed that you had set `pagingEnabled = YES` and suggested you do so.  That being said, it's unclear why exactly you're having trouble with scrolling.

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your reply, I do not have a problem with scrolling, what I'm trying to do is a little more dificult, I'm trying to add a gif image (index [4] ScrollView) 

Is it possible to make her?